# Error Message: Unfortunately Settings Has Stopped

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, system-error

When I tried to access `Settings > About Phone` today on my rooted Micromax a069 running Android 4.4.2 Kitkat, it displayed the error message, "Unfortunately Settings has stopped".

What might cause this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Has this happened before? Did you do something recently before this error occured?

Answer (score 2):

Just clear data and cache of **Settings** application under the phone by going into:

`Settings >> Apps >> All >> Settings >> Clear Cache`, then `Clear data`.

It should be working fine after doing this.